# XNA draw model partially

Tags: xna-4.0, models

Is it possible to draw a model partially (along the X, Y or Z axis) to make an extending barrier or something like that? (Scaling doesn't work because of the textures)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. There was a nice feature in XNA pre-4.0 called ClipPlanes. There are several good tutorials on how to use them, I'd recommend this one:

[Riemers XNA Tutorial - Clip planes](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series4/Refraction_map.php)

Now the problem is, ClipPlanes have been removed from XNA 4.0. Developers are supposed to implement it using shaders. I've found the following piece of code to do exactly this:

```
float4x4 World; 
float4x4 View; 
float4x4 Projection; 

float4 ClipPlane0; 

void vs(inout float4 position : POSITION0, out float4 clipDistances : TEXCOORD0) 
{ 
    clipDistances.x = dot(position, ClipPlane0); 
    clipDistances.y = 0; 
    clipDistances.z = 0; 
    clipDistances.w = 0; 

    position = mul(mul(mul(position, World), View), Projection); 
} 

float4 ps(float4 clipDistances : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0 
{ 
    clip(clipDistances); 

    return float4(0, 0, 0, 0); // TODO: whatever other shading logic you want 
} 

technique 
{ 
    pass 
    { 
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 vs(); 
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 ps(); 
    } 
}
```

I didn't test it myself, but I hope it helps.